# I don't understand why I have a dangling pointer

Tags: c++, string, lua, return-value, dangling-pointer

I have written this method:

```
std::string Utils::GetFileContents(const char* filePath)
{
    std::ifstream in(filePath, std::ios::binary);

    if (in)
    {
        std::string contents;
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.resize(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
        in.close();
        return(contents);
    }

    throw(errno + " ERROR: Could not open file.");
}
```

In another method, I have these instructions:

```
lua_State* state = luaL_newstate();

const char* code = Utils::GetFileContents(path).c_str();
luaL_dostring(state, code);

lua_close(state);
```

If you run your debugger in the previous method, you get a dangling pointer at the `code` variable. I do not understand why.

I found a way to make this work - to basically store `code` in a `std::string` and then change the next line to `luaL_dostring(state, code.c_str());`.

It doesn't make sense to me, as in both cases, `code` is stored as a `const char*`.

Comment: Where is your `std::string`? What happens when it "vanishes"?

Comment: `Utils::GetFileContents(path)` returns a temporary `std::string` instance, where `c_str()` dangles where the scope of the return value was left. So you need to have a copy existing in your client scope.

Comment: "...in both cases, code is stored as a const char*." A `const char *` cannot store a string. It can only refer to a string that exists somewhere else. When you use `c_str()` you get a pointer that refers to the string's data, but that pointer does not store that data. You need the string object to keep existing if you want to pointer to keep working.

Comment: "*It doesn't make sense to me*. " -- The bigger problem, since you said this, is that you may believe that `const char *` means "string data".  It doesn't.  A `const char *` is a pointer, nothing more, nothing less -- it is not a string.  A `const char *` has all of the vulnerabilities that any other pointer has (pointing to invalid memory, pointing to an object that no longer exists, etc.)

Comment: _"I don't understand why I have a dangling pointer"_  You seem to understand that you have a _pointer_.  When working with any pointer, you should be able to answer the question "when will this pointer dangle?"  That is, _what is it pointing to_ and _when will the thing pointed to no longer exist_?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux best explanation so far, I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function returns an object of the type `std::string`

```
std::string Utils::GetFileContents(const char* filePath)
```

You are assigning a pointer with the address of the first character of the returned temporary string

```
const char* code = Utils::GetFileContents(path).c_str();
```

After this declaration the returned temporary object will be destroyed. So the pointer `code` is invalid and using it in the next call

```
luaL_dostring(state, code);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You could write for example

```
std::string code = Utils::GetFileContents(path);
luaL_dostring(state, code.c_str());
```

Comment: @Slava Thanks. It was a typo.

Comment: it could be `const std::string &code = Utils::GetFileContents(path);` as well